# How do you list all tables and their foreign + primary keys in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

```
USE Database
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.tables 
WHERE type = 'PK' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID ('sys.tables')
GO
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    TableName = t.Name,
    IndexName = I.Name,
    FKName = fk.Name,
    ReferencedTable = refT.Name
FROM 
    sys.tables t
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.tables refT ON fk.referenced_object_id = refT.object_id
ORDER BY
    t.Name, i.Name
```

Lists all the tables and the primary key index (if present) and any foreign keys (and what other table that FK references)